# What kind of physician, if at all, adjusts a tattoo in human-skin-color and makes such tattoos to disguise scars?

Tags: dermatology

I understand from [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00266-011-9698-8) and from further general reading that tattooing is often done by physicians, or referred to by physicians, if a physician thinks it is the best option to disguise some scars (say, a small white scar on the hand of an otherwise `tanned-body-colored` human).

The linked article and other articles mentions Plastic surgeons and it can be understood that dermatologists do that as well, but I believe some sub specialty is needed because I have never encountered or found, at least for the sake of just finding a plastic surgeon or dermatologist specializing in "tattooing" (at least not in `human-skin-color` tattooing but on **scalp** with `scalp-micropigmentation` which is generally in `human-hair-color` and not in `human-skin-color`)

I did find an abundance of dermatologists who offer tattoo removal but not `human-skin-color` tattooing.

What kind of physician, if at all, adjusts a tattoo in `human-skin-color` and makes such tattoos to disguise scars?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen photos of tattoos done for those who have had surgery for breast cancer, ([example - **not safe for work**](https://breastcancernow.org/information-support/facing-breast-cancer/living-beyond-breast-cancer/your-body/decorative-tattoos-after-breast-cancer-surgery)) and in these cases it can be to hide the fact they have no nipple(s) as well as to hide scarring.

For what you are talking about, I would have said any registered and licensed tattooist who is good at mixing the colours would be able to do it. One point I would make though is that when wanting specific colouring, [tattoo colours do fade over time](https://authoritytattoo.com/tattoo-fading/) so you may need retouching work done after a time if you wish to maintain the same depth of colour.

> While [all tattoo fade](https://authoritytattoo.com/do-all-tattoos-fade/) *[sic]*, color tattoos certainly will fade quicker if you don’t take good care of them from the outset. Light colors will generally fade quicker than darker colors, with white ink being the one that will usually fade the quickest out of all the colors.
>
> Watercolor and pastel-color tattoos also generally fade much faster than others due to the fact that the technique generally requires much lighter and more delicate coloring.
>
> However, colored inks have improved considerably in recent years, and these enhancements help to prevent tattoos from fading as much as they would have a decade ago.

Comment: Hello ; thanks ; I would suggest an edit to change from `tattoo colours do fade over time` to `some tattoo colours do fade over time` because we I assume we cannot know which color materials each tattoo maker will use (but I can't do so because it's less than 6 characters change).

Comment: @JohnDoea - As far as I am aware, all tattoo colours fade over time so changing the text to that would be misleading.

Comment: Please consider an edit to add "generally" before that sentence ; I suggest this because in the past I have done a tattoo (which I already removed by laser) ; when I did the tattoo, I was promised it will fade after 5 years, but 8 years passed and it was appearing the same and bold until the remove by several laser sessions.

Comment: @JohnDoea - Again, that **could** be misleading. (See edit)

Comment: Chris, I personally think that writing something like "as a general rule", or "by principle", or "as far as I know" shouldn't be misleading --- humbly I personally think that not writing could be misleading --- I write this with appreciation for you personally and for the time you invested in answering me and helping others (and also up voted the answer).